# Как начать мультистрочное редактирование используя только клавиатуру?

Tags: sublime-text

Мне достаточно часто нужно написать какой-либо повторяющийся текст в начале\середине с какого-либо столбца. Когда использую NotePad++ я эту задачу решаю путем нажатия Ctrl+Shift и стрелок. В Sublime эта задача решается путем нажатия на среднюю кнопку мыши.

Мне не хочется "таскать" мышшь, а хочется использовать клавиатуру для этой маленькой задачки.

Как перенастроить multiline editing на Ctrl + Alt + клавиши стрелок?

Для уточнения того что хочу получить приведу ссылку на [видео ролик на YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrM1r23bBxs&list=PLxwwcy86tcqe02hFRzwSPHArw1xQFByih#t=791) на 13:12

Comment: Для уточнения привел ссылку на видеоролик(см. пост)

Comment: да, это ctrl+shift+l, только для начала нужно выделить нужный текст (shift + стрелки).

Comment: Да, можно использовать этот хоткей,но неудобно! Попробую пояснить. Есть мини-задача вставить в коде подстроку "optimize" скажем в 25 столбце.

Notepad++:
1) Подходим на нужный столбец;
2) Держим нажатыми Alt+Shift управляя стрелками выделяем строки;
3) Пишем нашу подстроку.

Итог : 3 действия

Sublime Text 2:
1) Держа нажатой Shift выделяем используя стрелки;
2) Нажимаем Ctrl+Shift+L;
3) Переходим к нужном столбцу;
4) Пишем нашу подстроку.

Итог: 4 действия

На одно действие Notepad++ выигрывает.

Comment: Значит используйте вим! тут все просто

    2 5 | <ctrl-v> j (нужное кол-во раз) I (вводим текст) <esc>

или

    2 5 | <ctrl-v> (нужное кол-во раз числом) j  I (вводим текст) <esc>

Comment: имеете в виду режим vim, т.е. вимтеч?

Comment: это был юмор - если Вам не нравиться один редактор, а другой не такой хороший, как нужно - используйте вим или эмакс.


а вот эмуляция вима в саблайме - это как пить безалкогольную водку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

даже на заглавной странице сайта саблима об этом сказано. С помощью shift+стрелки выделяете нужный кусок, потом жмете ctrl+shift+L и готово (если я конечно правильно понял, что имеется ввиду под многострочным редактированием у Вас)

Comment: В этом вопрос был принят ответ @KoVadim, который он написал ввиде комментария. Приведу его ответ:

> даже на заглавной странице сайта
> саблима об этом сказано. С помощью
> shift+стрелки выделяете нужный кусок,
> потом жмете ctrl+shift+L и готово
> (если я конечно правильно понял, что
> имеется ввиду под многострочным
> редактированием у Вас)

Вот если бы он написал сразу в виде ответа, а не комментария, то у меня была бы возможность пометить его как ответ и мой вопрос был бы закрыт. Вывод: комментариями имеющие возможность стать ответом не должны быть комментариями